# distribution of maximum random walk distance

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, random-walk, brownian-motion

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3889010/expected-number-of-maximum-difference-between-heads-and-tails/3995943#3995943).

Suppose I flip a fair coin $N$ times and keep track of the difference between the total number of heads and tails as I am doing it. At the end of the $N$ coin flips, I have the random variable defined as the maximum absolute value of the difference between the number of heads and tails during the entire experiment.

This sounds similar to the [law of interated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm), but not exactly. It doesn't really help with this problem, it's just a related topic.

I conjecture based on many simulations in scenarios including $N$ up to $10$ million that this random variable has mean approximately $1.25 \sqrt{N}$ and variance approximately equal to $0.26 N$.  The linked post above gives some bounds on the mean, but they are pretty wide. Are there any other things known about the distribution of this random variable?

Comment: Pearson, K. (1905). [Letters to the Editor: The Problem of the Random Walk](https://www.nature.com/articles/072342a0). *Nature*, 72(1867), 342.

Comment: Aside: How are you coding heads and tails? 1 and 0? 1 and –1? Something else?

Comment: @Alexis How could the choice of coding random variables affect the question (or even be relevant), which concerns differences of two counts?

Comment: @Alex I was using +1, -1 to make the mean 0 and the variance 1.

Comment: @Alexis I didn't know Karl Pearson had a good sense of humor.

Comment: Also I gave the wrong citation! (The citation I intended has the identical name, but different issue… the first citation I gave is a response to responses to this one.) The first random walk letter: Pearson, K. (1905). [Letters to the Editor: The Problem of the Random Walk](https://www.nature.com/articles/072294b0). *Nature*, 72(1865), 294.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference can be viewed as the sum of $2 B_i-1$ where $B_i$ are iid Bernoulli random variables.  After $n$ flips, the difference is approximately $N(0,n)$.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Running_maximum) for the distribution of the running maximum of a Weiner process and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126681/distribution-of-max-t-in-0-1-w-t-for-brownian-motion/3126708#3126708) for the distribution of the running maximum of the absolute value of a Wiener process.

For example, with $N=1000$ the mean and variance are approximately 39.63 and 260.75 using the provided formula from the link for the distribution according to numerical calculations in Mathematica.

```
Num = 1000.;

NIntegrate[
 1 - (4/Pi) NSum[
    Exp[-(2 n + 1)^2 Pi^2 Num/(8 r^2)] ((-1)^n )/(2 n + 1), {n, 0, 
     Infinity}], {r, 0, 120}]

NIntegrate[
 1 - (4/Pi) NSum[
    Exp[-(2 n + 1)^2 Pi^2 Num/(8 r)] ((-1)^n )/(2 n + 1), {n, 0, 
     Infinity}], {r, 0, 120^2}]

1831.371532331003` - (39.631070838003225`)^2
```

Now, notice that $P[\frac{max}{\sqrt{N}}<t]=P[max<t \sqrt{N}]$ and therefore the mean and variance of $\frac{max}{\sqrt{N}}$ is the same as the mean and variance of the running maximum of the absolute value of the Wiener process when $t=1$. That is, mean of approximately 1.253 and variance of 0.26. I don't know if there is any way to evaluate those analytically, I evaluated them numerically in Mathematica.

Update: I found a formula for the asymptotic value of the mean by interchanging the integration with the sum above (using [Cesaro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)). $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{N}\approx 1.25331\sqrt{N}$. That doesn't work for the variance though because the integral doesn't converge.